# getting an error for on Demand Workflow in CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am getting below error while running on demand workflow.The on demand workflow is simply create the record by copying the content of record.This Error occurs when I select multiple records and run the on demand workflow. If I select only one record and run the workflow then its working fine.

There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom plug-ins that ignore errors from service calls and continue processing.

Plugin Trace:

```C#
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.CreateEntity]
[CreateStep1: Create a Clone Lead]
Error Message:

Unhandled Exception:
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, 
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:
There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom plug-ins that
ignore errors from service calls and continue processing.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
```

-2147220911
   
   There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom plug-ins that ignore errors from service calls and continue processing.
   2013-10-15T10:51:50.8984331Z
   
    -2147220911
    
    There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom plug-ins that ignore errors from service calls and continue processing.
    2013-10-15T10:51:50.8984331Z
    
    
    
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow:   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.CreateEntity]
    [CreateStep1: Create a Clone Lead]
    
    
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Create(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.<>c_*DisplayClass1.   b*_0(IOrganizationService sdkService)
    at   Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ActivityServiceBase.ExecuteInTransactedContext(ActivityDelegate activityDelegate)
    at  Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.ExecuteInternal(ActivityContext executionContext, CreateEntity createEntity)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.Execute(ActivityContext executionContext, CreateEntity createEntity)
    at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
    at  System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a plug-in code in which there is a `continue;` statement inside a `catch` block which is triggering on an action being done by the workflow. If it is so, you need to take out the `continue;` statement from the `catch`.